# Mulesoft: How do I update a Salesforce object without an id

Tags: update, mulesoft

I am creating a flow in which I am first pulling data from MSSQL and then need to use the values from that query to update existing records in Salesforce.

However I don't have the records' ids in the MSSQL table. Instead I have the parent Ids of the records I need to update.

Let's imagine that the records I try to update are part of the myObj__c in Salesforce.

myObj__c has a master-detail relationship to Account.

The MSSQL table contains the Account Ids for the parent Accounts(field would be Account__c in SF).

The MSSQL table also contains the value of the field I need to update(let's call it theField__c).

In other words what I get from MSSQL looks like this:

```
[
    {
        accountId: "123456",
        theField: "my value"
    },
    {
        accountId: "1234890",
        theField: "my other value"
    }
]
```

I need to use that to populate myObj__c in Salesforce. I need to find the corresponding instances of myObj__c that map to these values based on the account ids. Then I need to update theField__c with the adequate value.

After conducting some research it seems that I cannot use Update or Update Multiple. Is that true?

What would be the best approach in this case? I can easily create an apex rest method in Salesforce but I was trying to avoid writing any apex code if I don't have to and instead use the full capabilities of Mulesoft.

Comment: One of the approach could be to query all records in salesforce, and then do joinBy, so you join by accountId and theField__c (https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dataweave-cookbook-merge-multiple-payloads)

Comment: @kurunve thanks, it seems like that could work for my scenario!